# javascript get value of <select>

Tags: javascript, select

I know that i can do something like that 
    document.getElementById("whatever").value
But i have code like that

```
<select id="year_architecture_third_choose" style="display: none">
                    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                    <option value="207">Lectures</option>
                    <option value="208">Courses</option>
                    <option value="209">Sheets</option>
                    <option value="210">Others</option>
                  </select>
                  <select id="year_architecture_fourth_choose" style="display: none">
                    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                    <option value="211">Lectures</option>
                    <option value="212">Courses</option>
                    <option value="213">Sheets</option>
                    <option value="214">Others</option>
                  </select>
                  </select>
               <select id="year_architecture_second_choose" style="display: none">
                <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                <option value="203">Lectures</option>
                <option value="204">Courses</option>
                <option value="205">Sheets</option>
                <option value="206">Others</option>
              </select>
```

This is just a small part of the code . I don't want to make `getElementById()` for each one i need better idea

Comment: Apply a the same class to each select and then retrieve them using getElementsByClassName()

Comment: Better Idea in the sense what you want to do? Try to be more clear please.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: if select (Electrical department) other list open to select the (Year) then a list appear to select ( lecture courses sheets others)

Comment: @bfavaretto the value define where the file will be uploaded

Comment: Basically the answer is what Darin Dimitrov posted. What you do inside the loop depends on your logic do handle the values. And if you need the fields `id`, you'll be able to get it the same way you'll be reading each value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `document.geteElementsByTagName('select')` method which will return a collection of all `<select>` elements in your DOM that you could then loop through and do whatever you originally intended to do on the element.

Reference: [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: great that what i was looking for